# Map workspace switch to mouse buttons in cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, workspaces, cinnamon

I want to set up cinnamon to switch workspaces right and left when I press my mouse scroll wheel clicker right or left, but I don't see an option in the cinnamon settings. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I _think_ that the mouse scroll wheel clicker right or left are treated as "left arrow" and "right arrow" by the OS. At least that was the case when I had a mouse that did this a few years ago, by mapping "Right arrow" to a function in vlc, I could execute that function using the mouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I think this is most appropriate to list as a separate answer, 2.5 years later]

It is possible to do this with the assistance of `xbindkeys`.

Install (`#apt-get install xbindkeys`), and then add this to the bottom of `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
# Previous desktop
"dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.Cinnamon /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.switchWorkspaceLeft"
  b:6

# Next desktop
"dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.Cinnamon /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.switchWorkspaceRight"
  b:7
```

(`b:6` and `b:7` are respectively the left and right rocker buttons on my mousewheel -- ymmv; use `xev` to work out the correct indices).

`xbindkeys` should reload its own configuration automatically, but you may need to force it with `killall -HUP xbindkeys`.  You may also need to log out and in again after installing it for the first time.

Comment: I needed to add `+ Release` for it to work, as in `b:8 + Release`. Otherwise, perfect!

Comment: This is the perfect solution to work with `xserver-xorg-input-mtrack` to reproduce OSX workspaces change / swipe.

Comment: Just a note for those that use imwheel / mousewheel.sh (https://github.com/hansfilipelo/bin/blob/master/mousewheel.sh) for setting the wheel scroll speed. You'll have to restart it for the above to work. Took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also really keen on getting this working (it's one thing I *really* miss from `compiz`!).  Right now, as far as I'm aware, the Cinnamon/Muffin API doesn't seem to expose the necessary events, but as soon as it does I will write an extension to do this.  In the mean time, there is [an extension available](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/17) that I'm using as a second-best solution.  Perhaps it will be helpful for you too.

Comment: to upvoter -- added a new answer below which may be attractive.